# Jackson / No serializer found for class

Tags: scala, serialization, neo4j, jackson, spring-data-neo4j

Neo4j server provides a REST api dealing with Json format.
I use spring-data-neo4j to map a domain object (in Scala) to a neo4j node easily. 
Here's an example of my User node:

```
@NodeEntity
class User(@Indexed @JsonProperty var id: UserId)
```

`UserId` being a value object:

```
final case class UserId(value: String) {
  override def toString = value
}

object UserId {
  def validation(userId: String): ValidationNel[IllegalUserFailure, UserId] =
    Option(userId).map(_.trim).filter(!_.isEmpty).map(userId => new UserId(userId)).toSuccess(NonEmptyList[IllegalUserFailure](EmptyId))
}
```

At runtime, I got this error:

```
Execution exception[[RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No      serializer found for class com.myApp.domain.model.user.UserId and no properties discovered to       create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)        ) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["value"])]]
```

Then, I came across this little [article](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/iU3Mna) on the web, explaining a solution.

I ended up with this `User` class:

```
@NodeEntity
@JsonAutoDetect(Array(JsonMethod.NONE))
class User (@Indexed @JsonProperty var id: UserId)
```

I also tried to put the `@JsonProperty` on the `UserId` value object itself like this:

```
JsonAutoDetect(Array(JsonMethod.NONE))
final case class UserId(@JsonProperty value: String) {
  override def toString = value
}
```

but I still get exactly the same error.

Did someone using Scala already had this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that case classes don't generate the JavaBean boilerplate (or member fields annotated appropriately) Jackson expects. For example, I believe Scala generates this method in `UserId`:

```
public java.lang.String value();
```

Jackson doesn't know what to do with that. It isn't a recognizable field or a JavaBean-style method (i.e. `getValue()` or `setValue()`).

I haven't yet used it, but you might want to try [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) as a more Scala-aware wrapper around Jackson. Another option is [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json).

Comment: That makes sense. However, I don't figure out why only field marked as `@Indexed` failed. If I drop the annotation over the `UserId`field, the whole pass without any Jackson annotation.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with `User` being a conventional class (whereas `UserId` is a case class). I love Jackson, but I strongly recommend you use a Scala-aware JSON serializer/deserializer, which as I said could just be the Jackson wrapper. For me personally, this kind of minutiae doesn't interest me, and I want this stuff to just work so I can focus on the interesting problems.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that the version of Jackson that you appear to be using (1.x) is not matching up the "value" property to the constructor argument. When applied to constructors, `@JsonProperty` usually requires a name parameter to match up parameters to properties; with your current setup, I believe the following would work:

```
case class UserId @JsonCreator() (@JsonProperty("value") value: String)
```

The Jackson Scala Module also provides more support for Scala-isms, and might possibly handle the `UserId` class without any Jackson-specific annotations. That said, your version of Jackson is quite old (the current latest version is 2.3.1), and upgrading might not be trivial for your configuration.

Comment: That works! :) I was missing the annotation `@JsonCreator()`. I currently use the old version since that is Spring-data-neo4j-rest that brings it. I will ask them to update it if possible. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: However, the `@Indexed` isn't taking into account any more. Where should I place the `@Indexed` annotation? I tried this:  `case class UserId @JsonCreator()(@JsonProperty("value") @Indexed value: String)` or this: `class User(@Indexed @JsonProperty var id: UserId)`  ..

Comment: You need to set the target of the `@Indexed` annotation to appear on the field, so neo4j can find it. The syntax is: `@(Indexed @field)`, where `field` is `scala.annotation.target.field` in Scala 2.9, and `scala.annotation.meta.field` in Scala 2.10.

Comment: Actually I use this custom annotation to avoid the issue with Scala annotation: `type Indexed = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Indexed@field`. Could it do the trick or your syntax has a different behavior?

Comment: Looking at the docs it *should* work, but I don't use neo4j so I can't be certain. Your custom annotation is just an alias for the syntax I posted.

Comment: I can confirm this worked when I set my value to be a simple `String` and not the value object `UserId`. It seems that `@Indexed` is bypassed when `@JsonProperty` is set.

Comment: I would deduce, instead, that neo4j can't use a custom type as an index. The presence or absence of `@JsonProperty` should not affect the outcome.

Comment: Yes...It seems.. the weird thing I noticed is that mapping for value object works for every field that is not indexed with `@Indexed`. I can write `class User(var id: UserId)`, it will well work even without the `@JsonProperty` set within the `UserId`. To sum up, when a field has `@Indexed`, mapping of value Object doesn't work. I wonder why there isn't such a problem when there isn't `@Indexed`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's not working: the JSON mapping, or the db persistence. If it's JSON mapping, I'd probably need to see the code in more detail to comment. I recommend following up on the Jackson user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jackson-user

Comment: I've just read the source code of spring-data-neo4j. I can confirm IMHO, that a custom type isn't possible. Indeed, the indexed property is set as "numeric" by default and the code then is: `public static boolean isNumeric(final Class<?> fieldType) {
        return (fieldType.isPrimitive() && !fieldType.equals(boolean.class) && !fieldType.equals(void.class)) 
            || fieldType.equals(Character.class)
            || (fieldType.getName().startsWith("java.lang") && Number.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType));
    }`  only primitives are possible. That's too bad, but I hope this will evolve;)